# is there any way to project/retrieve document fields in alphabetical order in mongo?

Tags: mongodb

Ex: document ABC contains fields  B, C, A, X, P (in random order)

`db.ABC.find()` will give results in  B, C, A, X, P (in random order) in table view

is there any way to get Documents fields in alphabetical order like A, B, C, P, X ?

Comment: You'll have to do this kind of ordering outside of mongo or explicitly use a [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projection)

Answer (score 0):

```
> db.order.insert({ b: '1', c: '2', a: '3', x: '4', p: '5' })
> db.order.aggregate([{ $project: { a: '$a', b: '$b', c: '$c', p: '$p', x: '$x' } }])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5df39e1389aa50dbce5b5157"), "a" : "3", "b" : "1", "c" : "2", "p" : "5", "x" : "4" }
```

But I don't think you can make mongo do that for you, only with usage of js script, which is then better move to code:

```
Object.keys(original).sort().reduce((result, key) => {
  result[key] = original[key];
  return result;
}, {});
```